# Integrating old fb:comments with the new comment moderation tool

Tags: facebook

I have a website that uses the old fb:comments:

```
<fb:comments xid="2" title="My website" notify="true" url="http://www.mywebsite.com/"></fb:comments>
```

My client asks me to integrate the new comment moderation tool, but it does not seem to accept the old comments entered with the old fb:comments.

If I try to implement the new fb:comments, I lose my old comments (aprox. 200). Does anyone know how could I add support to the comment moderation tool? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a link on Facebook with the solution:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472/

We need to add the migrated="1" attribute to our old fb:comments using xid as identifiers. In this way we can keep the old comments and use the moderation tool.